# Run a C++ file from a Script in Linux

Tags: c++, bash

I am in need of a code that compiles and runs a C++ file (which I have used for image processing) say Open_camera.cpp from a script.
Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: If you know the command to compile the program and the command to execute it, then you can write the script very easily. What trouble are you having?

Comment: Well you can either write a compiler or use one which already exists.

Comment: @Dave I would recommend writing a compiler from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
g++ Open_camera.cpp
./a.out
```

?

Answer (score 0):

If you have

```
// hello.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

You can write

> gcc -o hello.exe hello.cpp

That means:

- use gcc to compile the file hello.cpp
- -output is hello.exe, link all the stuff into it

Notice that gcc is the GNU compiler collection, if you pass it a C++ file it will invoke g++ (the C++ compiler) under the scenes